# Why is my dictionary not counting occurrences correctly?

Tags: c, text, binary-tree, words

I'm entering words into a binary tree and also counting the number of times they appear.

This is the text file: http://pastebin.com/FY9ZTQX6

Here is my code so far. It all happens in the insert() function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
Name: Marcus Lorenzana
Assignment: Final
*/

/*binary tree struct to hold left and right node
as well as the word and number of occurrences*/
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}
node;

//,.:;-
int punctuation[4] = {0};

/*Function Prototypes*/
void insert(node ** dictionary, node * entry);
char* readFile(char* filename);
void printDictionary(node * tree);
void printPunctuation(); 
void toLower(char** word);
char *replace(char *st, char *orig, char *repl);; 



int main()
{

    char *word;
    char* filecontents = readFile("data.txt");
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt","r");


    //create dictionary node
    node *dictionary;
    node *entry;

    //read words and punctuation in from the text file
    word = strtok (filecontents, " \n");

    dictionary = NULL;

    //create and add lowercase entries into the dictionary
    //by calling insert function 
    while (word != NULL)
    {

        //store punctuation in it's own array of occurrences
        //since there are only 4 to watch out for
        if (word[0]==',') {
            punctuation[0]++; 
            word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
        } else if (word[0]=='.')  {
            punctuation[1]++; 
            word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
        }
         else if (word[0]==';')  {
            punctuation[2]++; 
            word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
        }
         else if (word[0]=='-')  {
            punctuation[3]++; 
            word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
        } 
         else if (word[0]=='$') {
            break;
        }
        //use binary tree to store unique words
         else {
            //convert word to lowercase first, so capital words
            //won't have precedence
            word = strlwr(word);
            //create entry node and call insert with dictionary being call by reference
            //so that is is mutable
            entry = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            entry->left = entry->right = NULL;
            entry->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(word)+1));
            entry->word = word;
            insert(&dictionary,entry);
            word = strtok (NULL, " \n");
        }

    }
    //print the dictionary of words and their number of occurrences
    printDictionary(dictionary);
    //print the punctuation and their number of occurrences
    printPunctuation();


    //find word to be replaced

    int found = 0;
    char buffer[250];
    char src[50] , dest[50];
    while(fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , fp) != NULL)
    {
        if(strchr(buffer , '<'))
        {
            found++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found)
    {
        fscanf(fp , "%s < %s" , src , dest);
    }

    //example of replace()
    FILE *fout = fopen("newdata.txt","w");
    filecontents = readFile("data.txt");

    fprintf(fout,"%s",replace(filecontents,src,dest));

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

/*inserts an entry into the dictionary in lexicographical order*/
void insert(node ** dictionary, node * entry)
{
    //if there are no entries, set dictionary point
    //to new one and set count to 1 
    if(!(*dictionary))
    {
        *dictionary = entry;
        (*dictionary)->count=1;
        return;
    }

    //compare word to see if it of higher
    //or lower alphabetical order
    int result = strcmp(entry->word,(*dictionary)->word);

    //if it is lower, place on the left
    if(result<0)
    {

        insert(&(*dictionary)->left, entry);
        (*dictionary)->count=1; 


    }
    //if it is higher, place on the right
    if(result>0)
    {

        insert(&(*dictionary)->right, entry);
        (*dictionary)->count=1; 


    }
    //if it is equal, don't create a new entry but update the count
    if(result == 0)
    {
        (*dictionary)->count++; 
    }

}

/*put file contents in string for strtok*/
char* readFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    char* content = calloc(size + 1, 1);

    fread(content,1,size,file);

    return content;
}

/*prints the dictionary in lexicographical order
and number of occurrences for each word*/
void printDictionary(node * dictionary)
{
    //traverse dictionary in lexicographical order
    if(dictionary->left)
    {
        printDictionary(dictionary->left);
    }
    //print word and number of occurrences
    printf("%s\n",dictionary->word);
    printf("=%d\n",dictionary->count); 

    if(dictionary->right)
    {
        printDictionary(dictionary->right);
    }
}

/*prints the punctuation and number of occurrences*/
void printPunctuation(){
    //,.:;-
    printf("\n, = %d",punctuation[0]); 
    printf("\n. = %d",punctuation[1]); 
    printf("\n; = %d",punctuation[2]); 
    printf("\n- = %d",punctuation[3]); 

}

/*replace word*/
char *replace(char *st, char *orig, char *repl)
{
    static char buffer[2000];
    char *ch;
    if (!(ch = strstr(st, orig)))
        return st;
    strncpy(buffer, st, ch-st);
    buffer[ch-st] = 0;
    sprintf(buffer+(ch-st), "%s%s", repl, ch+strlen(orig));
    return buffer;
}
```

This is the output I'm getting: http://pastebin.com/8qSPQkiM

Comment: Why are you passing in ** Dictionary?  Its only a node pointer, not an array of node pointers.  Dictionary should be equal to your first node if you're going to walk through it.

Comment: @Magn3s1um he's passing the address of a pointer, specifically the root of the dictionary bst. On initial inception it will be NULL and is modified by-ref on the first word insertion.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't think that's necessary.  Why not just set dictionary to null and then pass the pointer in normally? If dictionary ref is null, then malloc an intial spot for dictionary and set your first node pointer to it.  KISS rule

Comment: @Magn3s1um How do you propose to set the *initial* value in `dictionary` when you're passing it as a by-val parameter? Your statement "set your first node pointer to it" will be setting the value to a stack-var. You have two options for returning output-pointers in tree/list code like this. (1) pass a pointer by-ref and set it (as the OP has done), or (2) have the function *return* the pointer value and you set it externally. The latter is generally *NOT* preferred as it can leak memory if the function is invoked without saving the result.

Comment: @WhozCraig No, I understand you don't want to pass it by value, but by reference.  But why not just Dictionary = null;  Insert(&dictionary), and then Declare insert as Insert(node * Dictionary), and then malloc dictinoary if dictionary == null? Now, there are implementations of node/linked lists that use double pointers, but they declare each node as a double pointer rather than passing in a single pointer and converting it to a double pointer

Comment: @Magn3s1um see the recursive calls to said-same function. The OP's design for the tree nodes is correct, and in-fact lends itself nicely to leaf-node insertion using recursion has he has done. That is not where his problem lays. Your example passes the address of a pointer-to-pointer-to-node (&dictionary) to a function that by your own definition is expecting a pointer-to-node. It wouldn't even *compile*. It is possible (but not likely) we're not talking about the same things. Paste a sample on ideone.com or pastebin.com and I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by changing this:

```
        entry->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(word)+1));
        entry->word = word;
```

to this:

```
        entry->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(word)+1));
        strcpy(entry->word, word);
```

As it is now, you're leaking memory and storing a stack-var pointer, which eventually is invalid. You're code has other problems, but this is likely the most immediate problem you're facing.

Next, in `insert()`, you're incorrectly resetting counters on intermediate nodes. This:

```
//if it is lower, place on the left
if(result<0)
{
    insert(&(*dictionary)->left, entry);
    (*dictionary)->count=1; // <=== SHOULD NOT BE HERE
}

//if it is higher, place on the right
if(result>0)
{
    insert(&(*dictionary)->right, entry);
    (*dictionary)->count=1; // <=== SHOULD NOT BE HERE
}

//if it is equal, don't create a new entry but update the count
if(result == 0)
{
    (*dictionary)->count++; 
}
```

should be this:

```
if(result<0)
{
    insert(&(*dictionary)->left, entry);
}
else if (result>0)
{
    insert(&(*dictionary)->right, entry);
}
else
{   // found it. update the count
    (*dictionary)->count++; 
}
```

Comment: Same output. For instance for "my" there should be a lot more than "1"

Comment: After you find a word, you break out of the loop and never go back.  You need to scan the rest of the file even after a word is found, and not stop until the end (unless I'm reading it wrong....).